# How to set multiple values in a variable and use it in multiple DML statements in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was writing an SQL query to delete multiple entries from multiple tables and databases. I have tried this query for single entry and it worked. But when I was trying to pass multiple string in single go it gave me an error. Here was my code:

```
Declare @etableId varchar(200) ='STRING_111';

Use DB1
Begin
delete from EPId where PId=@etableId 
delete from CCT where PId =@etableId 
delete from Template where id=@etableId
End
 
Use DB2
Begin
Declare @GSID int;
Select @GSID = id from GS where EId=@etableId;
print @GSID
delete from Ticket where GSI = @GSID
delete from Subset where GSI = @GSID
delete GS where id = @GSID
delete from TP where PTID= @etableId
delete from TP where PTID = @etableId
delete from Temp where id = @etableId
End
```

I was trying to declare multiple string in the query like: "Declare @etableId varchar(200) =('STRING_111','STRING_222');". On executing this query, I am getting a Syntax error near , error. It does not accept multiple string value by this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried 'Table' variable to accept multiple values and it worked for me. Here is the code:

```
Declare @etableId TABLE
(
Value varchar(1000)
)

insert into @etableId values ('STRING_111')
insert into @etableId values ('STRING_222')
insert into @etableId values ('STRING_333')
    
Use DB1
Begin
delete from EPId where PId IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @etableId)
delete from CCT where PId IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @etableId)
delete from Template where id IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @etableId)
End
 
Use DB2
Begin
DECLARE @GSIDS TABLE (ID INT); 
INSERT into @GSIDS (ID) SELECT id FROM GS WHERE EId IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @etableId);    
delete from Ticket where GSI IN (SELECT ID FROM @GSIDS)
delete from Subset where GSI IN (SELECT ID FROM @GSIDS)
delete GS where id IN (SELECT ID FROM @GSIDS)
delete from TP where PTID IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @etableId)
delete from TP where PTID IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @etableId)
delete from Temp where id IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @etableId)
End
```

The above code accepts multiple values in a variable, which we can use in multiple DML statements.

Thanks.!

Comment: `Select @GSID = id from GS where EId IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @etableId);` <-- I'm not sure that does what you think it does. You will be assigning _some arbitrary_ value of `id`, not all of them.

Comment: This will work apart from here: `Declare @GSID int;; Select @GSID = id from GS where EId IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @etableId);`. If there are multiple variables in `@tableid` there are likely to be multiple rows in `GS` that match, so the scalar variable `@GSID` should probably also be a table variable. e.g. `DECLARE @GSIDS TABLE (ID INT); INSERT @GSIDS (ID) SELECT id FROM GS WHERE EId IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @etableId); DELETE Ticket WHERE GSI IN (SELECT ID FROM @GSIDS);`

Comment: Also if `Value` is unique then you should make it a primary key `Value varchar(1000) primary key` and you should match the data type to the column (which I assume is smaller)